# Earthquake Plotting using Pandas, from csv file

Tags: python, csv, pandas, matplotlib

I am new to anaconda package and python. I have to plot an earthquake data. I read on google that pandas uses matplotlib and csv. Following is the data.

```
time,mag,magType
2015-02-19T06:32:52.870Z,0.74,ml
2015-02-19T06:07:17.510Z,0.55,md
2015-02-19T06:07:03.720Z,1.01,md
2015-02-19T06:03:26.070Z,4.6,mb
2015-02-19T05:59:25.840Z,1.44,ml
2015-02-19T05:55:55.000Z,1.6,ml
2015-02-19T05:52:43.880Z,0.57,md
2015-02-19T05:45:01.820Z,0.71,ml
2015-02-19T05:39:25.430Z,0.41,ml
```

I need to convert the 2015-02-19T05:39:25.430Z into datetime format similar to 2015-02-19 05:39:25 and plot them on graph. The graph type I would like to use is a line graph.

Requirements - 
- Plot the time vs magnitude graph
- Plot the total occurences per week on the graph, where each occurence has a magnitude > 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define exactly what you want but just reading in the csv and passing params `parse_dates=[0] and index_col=[0]` will produce a df with your datetime as the index, with dtype datetime64, we can then just call `plot` on this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'c:\data\earthquake.csv', parse_dates=[0], index_col=[0])

df.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks EdChum. Actually I need plot a time vs magnitude graph. The time should be the full datetime format dd:mm:yyyy:hh:mm:ss. Also, I need to show the difference between to weeks. Consider there were 3 occurences in Week1 and 10 occurences in Week2. I need to show that on the graph. How may i do that?

Comment: What is plotted is the magnitude vs time, you need to edit into your question your complete requirements, your data is insufficient to use to meet your requirements anyway, with respect to what you're asking you can groupby whatever criteria you wish and plot this